# How to make an existing Editor window floatable

Tags: unity

I added a second inspector window tab to Unity and locked it. I tried moving it to another desktop on my Mac but it doesn't move to the next desktop. How can I make a duplicate Inspector Window floatable?

Answer (score 1):

Just hold the tab and drop it on the top of your screen.
It should make the window float able.

Step one: Hold the window you want to make float able.
[image]

Step two: Drag the window to the top of your screen (The maximum you are able to drag)
[image]

Step three: Release the mouse button and you got yourself a floating window.
[image]

Comment: I am not able to drag the floatable window to another desktop